# autolayout update image size when rotating

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, screen-rotation

I'm very new with auto layout. I have a simple UIViewController that contains a View and a UIImageView.

On portrait mode this image is 320x115px but I would like to reduce the image height when rotating to landscape.

Currently I have the following constraints on my image. 
-Height Equals 115px
-Trailing Space to superview
-Leading Space to superview
-Top Space to supverview

How to make my UIView have proportional vertical size when rotating from portrait to landscape?

Thanks for your help,

Sébastien.

Comment: How big is the image in the UIImageView?

Comment: The UIImageView is 320x115px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same proportional size as 115 is to 480 (0.24), then you use the multiplier parameter in constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:.

In the example below, I made an IBOutlet to the height constraint in IB (heightCon), then remove that in code and add another one that is based on a fraction of self.view's height (iv is my outlet to the image view):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.iv removeConstraint:self.heightCon];
    NSLayoutConstraint *newHeightCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:.24 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:newHeightCon];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do it directly from IB? I suppose I need to replace the constraints when the view is rotating from Portrait to Landscape and then to replace it again when the view is rotating from Landscape to Portrait? Right?

Comment: @user951368, no, there's no way to do this from IB -- unfortunately, we don't have access to the multiplier parameter in IB. I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence -- you don't need to do anything other than what I posted.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. Initially my view is displayed in Portrait mode, the UIImage size is 320x115px. Then the user rotates the iPhone to landscape, the height of the image must be scaled, I suppose I need to replace the constraint at the beginning of the rotation. Next, when the user will rotate back to portrait I will have to replace the constraint to restore the original height (115px). Is it right?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I have performed some test and now I better understand, it's equivalent to UIImageView.Height = parentView.Height * 0.24 + 0

It works, thanks a lot.